# Clearing number in a Label on Text Box Change

Tags: vb.net, label, overwrite, basic

Just have a simple question. I have a program and in it I have a label that displays results once you calculate them, and I want the label to clear once you change the text in the input boxes. Assuming the label is named like *lblResult* or something, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows Forms, you would handle the [`TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of your input box. In the event handler, you would then set your `lblResult.Text = ""`

If you are using WPF / XAML, the concept it the same, you'd just [handle the event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) a little differently.

You can learn more about VB.NET and Event Handlers on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172877.aspx).